# Bad argument (image must have CV_8UC3 type) in grabCut

Tags: ios, opencv

I am using grabCut algorithm using the following code:

```
cv::Mat img=[self cvMatFromUIImage:image];

cv::Rect rectangle(10,10,300,150);

cv::Mat result; // segmentation (4 possible values)
cv::Mat bgModel,fgModel; // the models (internally used)
// GrabCut segmentation
cv::grabCut(img,    // input image
            result,      // segmentation result
            rectangle,   // rectangle containing foreground
            bgModel,fgModel, // models
            3,           // number of iterations
            cv::GC_INIT_WITH_RECT); // use rectangle
// Get the pixels marked as likely foreground
cv::compare(result,cv::GC_PR_FGD,result,cv::CMP_EQ);
// Generate output image
cv::Mat foreground(img.size(),CV_8UC3,
                   cv::Scalar(255,255,255));
result=result&1;
img.copyTo(foreground, result);
            result);

image=[self UIImageFromCVMat:foreground];
ImgView.image=image;
```

The code to convert `UIImage` to `Mat image` looks like this

```
- (cv::Mat)cvMatFromUIImage:(UIImage *)imge
{
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGImageGetColorSpace(imge.CGImage);
    CGFloat cols = imge.size.width;
    CGFloat rows = imge.size.height;

    cv::Mat cvMat(rows, cols, CV_8UC4); // 8 bits per component, 4 channels

    CGContextRef contextRef = CGBitmapContextCreate(
                                        cvMat.data,     // Pointer to  data
                                        cols,           // Width of bitmap
                                        rows,           // Height of bitmap
                                        8,              // Bits per component
                                        cvMat.step[0],  // Bytes per row
                                        colorSpace,     // Colorspace
                                        kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast |
                                        kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault); 
                                               // Bitmap info flags

    CGContextDrawImage(contextRef, CGRectMake(0, 0, cols, rows), imge.CGImage);
    CGContextRelease(contextRef);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    return cvMat;
}
```

But I got the error

> OpenCV Error: Bad argument (image must have CV_8UC3 type) in grabCut.

If I change 
`cv::Mat cvMat(rows, cols, CV_8UC4);` line to `cv::Mat cvMat(rows, cols, CV_8UC3);`
then I get `<Error>: CGBitmapContextCreate: unsupported parameter combination: 8 integer bits/component; 32 bits/pixel; 3-component color space; kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast; 342 bytes/row.`.

I am confused here for what to do.

Any help please

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The Problem seems to be, that the image you get has an alpha channels, while grabcut expects a rgb image without an alpha channel. So you need to get rid of the additional channel.

You can do this for example with this function:

```
cv::cvtColor(img , img , CV_RGBA2RGB);
```

Comment: thanx @sietschie , it works, solve the error. But i still i am unable to get all foreground objects. Still background image appears in half screen. And can i make rectangle region from contours?

Comment: Without seeing your images it is hard to make a judgement. But of course it could be possible, that GrabCut is not able to segment your objects properly. And of course it is possible to get the bounding box of a contour. But if you want to use that as the input for GrabCut, I would suggest to convert it into a mask instead. That way you can leverage more of the information provided by the contours.

Comment: and in python ?

Comment: For me, it's cv::COLOR_RGBA2RGB